# Why is my font failing to draw? (or load?) -- Java

Tags: java, fonts, io

My fonts class:

```
// fall back font if init() fails
public volatile static Font fallbackFont = new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);

public synchronized static Font myFont() {
    Font myFont;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("res/fonts/gregorian.ttf");
        myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fis);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(myFont);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("myFont font failed to load.");
        return fallbackFont;
    }
    return myFont;
}
```

I then call `fonts.init()`, `g2d.setFont(myFont)`, and then `g2d.drawString("test")` in my render class.

I get no errors, and I don't get my exception message. However, the font displayed on screen is my fallback serif font, not my custom font. Why is this the case?

EDIT 2: this actually fixed it, there was another stupid error in my render class. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's java convention to only use all caps for things that are constants (i.e. a `final` or enums). That said, you are shadowing the gloabl `MYFONT` in your `init()` method with a local variable of the same name.

As a simpler example of this:

```
public int i = 0;

public void update() {
  int i = 10; // this does not in any way touch the above-declared "i"
}

public void updateProperly() {
  i = 10; // this _does_ use the above-declared "i"
}
```

You're doing the same with your `MYFONT` variable.

A better way to structure your code is to instead do this:

```
public static Font myFont = getFont();

public static Font getFont() {
  try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("res/fonts/MYFONT.ttf");
    return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fis);
  }
  // never catch "Exception", always catch the possible specific exceptions
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Fonts failed to load.");
  }
  // fallback option
  return new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, 24);
}
```

Comment: then please rerun your code, see what it's doing *now*, which will be very different, and don't just edit it to say "I updated it" but rephrase the whole thing because you're now experiencing a different problem =) (Also you're trying catching `Exception`. Don't; only catch the exception type that's actually being thrown). Also note that your new code is doing a very weird thing: it's not returning a font, it's either "loading a font and binding it graphics context" or "returning a font". Which is it? One method should do one thing, without side-effects.

Comment: This is a test method, with code grabbing from multiple different examples haha. Sorry that it is sloppy, it is my first time trying to load fonts.

Comment: Don't be sloppy when asking other human beings for help =) Reduce the code to an [mcve](/help/mcve) and then you have good code to ask a question about (and have better understand of, yourself, too)